# What can be done when many websites classify your website and email addresses as invalid?

Tags: email, domain

I own New gTLD Program website and email addresses - XXX.YYY.science and XXX@YYY.science.

My issue is that many websites that require those to be supplied while filling forms do not support [New gTLD Program domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains) such as .science, .camera, and .game.

Furthermore, some anti-spam engines classify email messages originated in those email addresses as spam.

For example, Facebook blocks my website address - it doesn't let me send it via private messages or share it anywhere; I have it defined under my contact information, but clicking on the link redirects to a "Link Blocked" page with the following message: "We believe the link you are trying to visit is malicious. For your safety, we have blocked it."

Another case is LinkedIn, which doesn't show and link to my email address correctly under Contact and Personal Info in my profile. Even though my email address is verified, it shows and links to: https://www.linkedin.com/redir/invalid-link-page?url=XXX%40YYY%2escience

Now, I could ask every single website to add an exception or add support for New gTLD Program domains, but it might take much time to do so, or won't even be possible, in case the website uses some third-party web form service.

Alternatively, I can use my Gmail address, but then I miss all the point of a standalone professional email address.

One of the aims of those new domains is to enhance the competition between domain vendors and make domains more affordable to personal needs and small businesses. But if they are not fully supported by many web and email services, including major ones, then I guess that something should or must be done in form of proper standardization of their integration, so that in a few years this issue would be solved.

What would be a possible action to take for the sake of all the New gTLD Program users?

Comment: Short of contacting every company that considers the address invalid and hoping that they fix the problem - not a lot I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a group known as "Universal Acceptance steering group" which want to promote the concept that all domain names should be treated equally. They are now letting people around the world to submit info about sites that not accept gTLD to them at https://uasg.tech/global-support-centre/ so that they would contact and track support status of different sites.

Alternatively you can also contact those site and request them to support gTLD addresses, some time it would work even more if you're contacting them in open and public way to put public pressure onto them.

Here is a blog I saw that talked about it a bit https://www.eurodns.com/blog/gtlds-email-addresses-and-universal-acceptance

A possible workaround could be registering yet another regular dotcom address and then redirect the dotcom address to your gTLD address.

Edit: Also, many email filtering programmes like SpamAssassin have been actively and consciously blocking email from new TLD as they seems to think these domain names send more spam mail. (Some info about a similar situation happened to.biz last decade: https://wordtothewise.com/2007/11/why-does-everyone-tell-you-to-avoid-biz-in-your-emails/ and some info on spam filters being updated to block these gTLDs: http://uribl.com )

Comment: I've been wondering if there is some common validation code or scriptlet that is proliferating, as more and more web sites are rejecting my gTLD domain address. I'm pleased to get this information. Doing something is better than doing nothing.